# Compile pbtxt into binarypb

Tags: mediapipe

I'm playing around with Mediapipe and I'm trying to better understand how the graph works and what is the input/output of the different calculators.

If I understand correctly, the `.pbtxt` files are just plain-text instructions that describe how each calculator should interact with the rest of the calculators. These files are compiled into `.binarypb` files, which are fed to Mediapipe.

For example, [this](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/graphs/face_mesh/face_mesh_desktop_live.pbtxt) `.pbtxt` file got compiled into [this](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh@0.4.1633559619/face_mesh.binarypb) `.binarypb` file.

I have a few questions:

1. I saw https://viz.mediapipe.dev/ , which seems to be Mediapipe's playground. That playground seems to be compiling the text in the textarea on the right. If that is correct, how does it do it? Is there any documentation I can read about it? How are `.pbtxt` compiled into `.binarypb`?
2. I'm especially interested in the web capabilities of mediapipe and I'd like to create a small POC using both face-mesh and depth-to-iris features. Unfortunately, [there isn't](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/solutions.html) a "solution" for the second one, but [there is a demo in Mediapipe's viz](https://viz.mediapipe.dev/demo/iris_depth) claiming depth-to-iris web support (the demo doesn't seem to be working correctly though). If I were able to create a `.pbtxt` with a pipeline containing the features that I'm interested into, how would I ¿compile? the `.wasm` and `.data` files required to deploy the code to the web?